# pass an array of structure through function using matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm working on MATLAB for image processing.I have a problem where we search the 3x3 neighbours of a pixel. If there are 2 or more neighbours then we store the number of neighbours and the pixel coordinates in a structure. The problem is I'm not able to pass this structure to the calling function.my structure is like this:

```
pixel=struct('count',{},'x',{},'y',{});

struct pixel p[]={};

for x=2:size(PEI,1)-1

   for y=2:size(PEI,2)-1

       if(PEI(x,y)==1)

            p=windowmod(x,y);
       end

   end

end
```

Then I declare a function:

```
function [p]=windowmod(x1,y1)
```

When I run the code I get the following error:

```
??? Output argument "p" (and maybe others) not assigned during call to
"C:\Users\Prajnya\Desktop\IP programs\windowmod.m>windowmod".

    Error in ==> step5modified at 17
               p=windowmod(x,y);
```

I don't understand what this error means. I would be extremely grateful if someone could help me with this function.

Comment: Please post your code for `windowmod`.  We can't diagnose what exactly is wrong without it.  However, that error is very clear.  You need to look into your `windowmod` function and make sure that `p` is returned once it finishes.  You get that error because `p` is not returned upon completion of `windowmod`.

Comment: @rayryeng is correct. The value p is never assigned within the windowmod function, either because it cannot be reached within loop or if statement, or simply is not existent.

Comment: Also, it looks like you are mixing c and matlab syntax in a single block of code.

Comment: @Juderb - It's funny.  The second line of code actually works.  I tried it just now.  It simply creates an empty structure that has the same fields as `pixel`.... don't know why it works, but it's most certainly confusing.

Comment: Something new to check out then. Awesome!

Comment: In octave this is calling `struct('pixel','p[]={}');` which creates a struct with the field pixel which contains `'p[]={}'`
`

Comment: @Daniel - Cheers mate.  That syntax was very confusing.

Comment: @rayryeng - I know its confusing. I'm actually looking for a better solution to go about the problem. I need to have something like a tree search algorithm but with multiple branches instead of just 2 at each node.

Comment: @prajnya - Did you even look at what we suggested?  Forget about talking about what it is you're doing, we are telling **why you are getting that error**.